# I can't survive without coffee everyday

Tags: idiomatic-language

I want to say that I need to drink coffee everyday, otherwise I can't survive.

Is it idiomatic to say:

> It's not bearable for not having a coffee in a day;
>
> I can't go without coffee everyday;
>
> I can't go a day without coffee;
>
> I can't survive without coffee everyday.

or there is a better way of saying it?

Comment: *Everyday* means common or ordinary. You're better off with "every day."

Comment: Another possible way: "I'm addicted to coffee."  "I'm a coffee addict."  "I have a coffee addiction."

Answer (score 1):

Sentences 1 and 2? Nonstandard. 
Sentences 3 and 4? Fine.

In particular, sentence 1 is nongrammatical. Sentence 2 says, "I can't go every day without coffee," which is logically equivalent to, "I need there to be at least one day when I have coffee."